# Unable to get Supabase signed URL in a NextJs ImageLoader

Tags: typescript, next.js, async-await, supabase, nextjs-image

I am creating a web app using NextJS and Supabase. I have a bucket on supabase containing images that I would like to be available only to select users. If I get the signed url first, and then create Images that use this as the src, I am able to get them to load as I want.

I also have images on the site stored in a public bucket, that I load using an ImageLoader as shown here: [Supabase Docs - Using NextJS Loader](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/storage/image-transformations#nextjs-loader). This also works.

The problem is that I'm implementing what feels like two very different solutions to almost the same problem and i would like to use the same method for both. I prefer the second method of using a loader (it feels like a cleaner implementation, it allows me to pass in the image transforms in a single step, and it allows me to use the Image Placeholder) so that is what I am trying to do.

I've hit a roadblock here as there seems to be no synchronous way to get the signing token, and the loader cannot return a promise.

So I need either a synchronous way to get the token from Supabase, or a way to use an async loader function in NextJs.

My best attempt so far:

```
import { ImageLoader } from 'next/image'
import { useSupabaseClient } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-react";

const signedSupabaseLoader: ImageLoader = ({ src, width, quality }) => {
    const supabase = useSupabaseClient()

    var splitSrc = src.split('/')
    const bucketId = splitSrc.shift() as string
    const filePath = splitSrc.join('/')


    const { data, error } = await supabase
        .storage
        .from(bucketId)
        .createSignedUrl(filePath, 60, {
            transform: {
                width,
                quality
            }
        })

    if (error) console.log(error);
    if (data?.signedUrl) return data?.signedUrl
    return src
}

export default signedSupabaseLoader
```

It obviously doesn't work as I'm calling await in a function that isn't async, but I cant change  the either function type

Comment: "So I need either a synchronous way to get the token from Supabase, or a way to use an async loader function in NextJs." Neither of them exists. You just simply have to get signed URL using standard data fetching. https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/fundamentals